# Rename file name using uploadify

Tags: php, uploadify, codeigniter-2

i am uploading a image using uploadify,the problem is,in the model i am changing the file name which is pass by uploadify funciton.now i want that file name which is renamed in model in onUploadComplete property of uploadify.Im alerting that file name but it display the same file name which actually uploading.
here is my code:-

```
        'buttonText'      : 'Select',
        'fileTypeDesc'    : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts'    : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
        'swf'             :'<?php echo base_url()?>resources/flash/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'        :'<?php echo base_url().'user/upload_temp';?>',
        'width'           : 40,
        'multi'           :false,
        'onUploadComplete':function(file)
        {
            alert(file.name);
            $('.select_div').hide();
            $('.original').hide();
            $('#image1').attr('style','background-image:url("./resources/images/users/temp/'+file.name+'");background-size: 76px 76px;');
            $('.default').hide();
            $('#image2').attr('style','background-image:url("./resources/images/users/temp/'+file.name+'");background-size: 73px 66px;position:absolute; height:66px; width:73px; top:256px; left:220px;');
            $('#hidden_img_value1').attr('value',file.name)
        }
    });
```

and in model im doing like this :-
    $targetFolder =  FCPATH.'/resources/images/users/temp/'; // Relative to the root
        if (!empty($image)) 
        {
            $time=strtotime("now");
            $image['Filedata']['name']=$time.'.jpg';
            $tempFile = $image['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = $targetFolder.$image['Filedata']['name'];

```
        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($image['Filedata']['name']);

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetPath);
            echo '1';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($image['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) 
    {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetPath);


      // Set new Name
      $new_name = rand(0,10000).'.'.$fileParts['extension'];
      $new_path = $fileParts['dirname'].'/'.$new_name;

      while(file_exists($new_path))
     {
      $new_name = rand(0,10000).'.'.$fileParts['extension'];
      $new_path = $fileParts['dirname'].'/'.$new_name;
     }

      rename($targetPath,$new_path);

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Opps , Correct function is file_exists() use this while(file_exists($new_path))

Comment: I tried this but still not alerting the file which is renamed in model.after renaming my file is stored ok but i want that renamed file onUploadComplete. i am alerting file.name onUploadComplete it shows the actual file name not rename file name plzz help on this as soon as possible

Comment: Echo old file name on the PHP Script , $oldfile = $fileParts['filename'].'.'.$path_parts['extension']; echo $oldfile; and you can get the old file name  'onUploadComplete':function(file){ var name = file.name; }

Comment: Uploadify just pickup the response data of upload script and display back to the page , just like jquery $.post(); , so echo whatever you want to get,

Comment: still not getting my rename file name in onUploadComplete

Comment: For Getting new file name echo $new_name;

Comment: You need to use onUploadSuccess. The event 'onUploadComplete' does not accept a data argument. http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/